# How can I move all content of catalog?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have:

`/home/www/project`

and

`/home/www/project/test_git`

How can I move all content of `test_git` catalog into:

`/home/www/project` ?

Comment: See [Bash: How can I move all the content in the folder up to one level?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9964082/2353900)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mv /home/www/project/test_git/* /home/www/project/`

Comment: @Rinzwind Again I tended to downvote a comment... ;) No, it will not fail. Moreover, `mv` doesn't have such a option - `-r`. Please read `man mv` for more info.